# Erro ao adicionar ON DELETE CASCADE duas foreign keys provenientes da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, chave-estrangeira, constraint

Estou implantando uma tabela para salvar as mensagens, nesta tabela eu tenho usuarios de origem(remetente) e usuario de destino(destinatário) provenientes da mesma tabela: usuário.

Ao tentar adicionar as constraints na tabela de mensagens, tenho o seguinte erro: A introdução da restrição `FOREIGN KEY` `FK_MOVMSGCHT_IDCUSRDST` na tabela `MOVMSGCHT` pode causar ciclos ou vários caminhos em cascata. Especifique `ON DELETE NO ACTION` ou `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, ou modifique outras restrições `FOREIGN KEY`.

Existe alguma maneira de usar `DELETE CASCADE` neste caso?

Comment: Pergunta interessante, nestes casos jamais pensaria em CASCADE. Se tenho solução ? Não.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta inverter a ordem do delete, primeiro o destinatário e depois a origem, ou vice versa.
Tipo

```
ALTER TABLE `origem`
ADD CONSTRAINT `destino_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`destino_id`) 
  REFERENCES `destino` (`destino_id`);
```

Ou vai pelo lado mais fácil, mas que não é uma solução correta.
Desligar o keycheck

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- desliga
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- religa
```

Comment: E o perguntador some ...